# Hide 8080 on URL and redirect traffic from 80 to 8080

Tags: tomcat, configuration, glassfish

I got two enterprise applications running on the same machine and with JKMount I have managed to redirect traffic from 8081 to one of them and 8082 to another, but now I also need to deploy a Web service. I have deployed the Web service and it is accesible at `http://localhost:8080/xyz/abcd?wsdl`.

I want to remove the port from the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) and make the traffic pass instead of 8080, on port 80 and to be redirected to 8080, because I already have another service running and occupying the port 80.

How can I do that by configuring [Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) and [GlassFish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that only one process can listen to a specific port at the same time. So if there is already an application using port 80 you will have to configure a proxy for this application.

Or, alternatively, you set the blocking application to be listening to some other port and use a proxy.

If you have root access to the machine, you can use a proxy via Apache + [mod_proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod_proxy) or [Cherokee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherokee_%28web_server%29), to redirect external requests on port 80 (or any other Apache-listening port) to some specific internal port (or even to ports on other servers).

Comment: OK I understand that there is only one process listening on that port. So I can redirect requests containing /xyz/ from port 80 to port 8080 using proxy?

Comment: Yes. e.g. the browser URL looks like http://test.com/myapp and the tomcat-webapp is deployed on localhost:8080/myapp a proxy redirect looks like (in Apache mod_proxy):
ProxyPass /myapp http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp
ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp

Answer (score 1):

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080

iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080

iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443

iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443
```